# Unable to get Module Cronjob working

Tags: module, magento-1, cron

I've seen a few other questions about this with similar issues, but I can't seem to duplicate their fixes with my structure and Namespace/Moduel name etc.

I've got the following files:

**Namespace/PendingCancellation/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_PendingCancellation>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_PendingCancellation>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <pendingcancellation>
                <class>Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model_Observer</class>
            </pendingcancellation>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <PendingCancellation_Update>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>pendingcancellation/observer::cancelPendingOrders</model>
                </run>
            </PendingCancellation_Update>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**Namespace/PendingCancellation/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model_Observer
{
    public function cancelPendingOrders()
    {
        Mage::log('Cron run', null, 'test.log');
    }
}
```

I know I'm likely doing something very obvious and or stupid but would very much appreciate the help after staring at this for a while.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared your models incorrectly in `config.xml`:

```
<class>Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model_Observer</class>
```

should instead just be:

```
<class>Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model</class>
```

The string you enter here acts as starting point to find the location of the class according to how you refer to the model.  So you have:

```
pendingcancellation/observer::cancelPendingOrders
```

in your cron job.  The first thing that happens here is that the models relating to `pendingcancellation` are looked for, in your case you have declared your models resource as follows in config.xml:

```
...
<models>
    <pendingcancellation>
        <class>Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model_Observer</class>
    </pendingcancellation>
</models>
...
```

This means that Magento will use `Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model_Observer` as the start of the class name of your observer.  After `pendingcancellation` you have `observer`.  This makes up the rest of the class name,  and so in this case translates to a class name of `Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model_Observer_Observer` which is not correct.

When declaring your resources in `config.xml` you should only ever declare the class name up to `_Model`/`_Block`/`_Helper` etc. as the rest of the class name is determined by the argument you send to the method which instantiates the class, which in this case is `pendingcancellation/observer::cancelPendingOrders`.

Comment: Ok, you're answer is waaay better. Great explanation!

Comment: I made the change, cleared out the cron_schedule table and ran cron.php a couple of times but it still doesn't appear to be being scheduled.

Comment: Are any other jobs not queueing?

Comment: Now that you mention it, not since I've cleared the schedule table, no nothing is queueing...

Answer (score 2):

You used the full observer class in your global models tag. It should be

```
<global>
   <models>
      <pendingcancellation>
         <class>Namespace_PendingCancellation_Model</class>
      </pendingcancellation>
   </models>
</global>
```

Optionally, to debug cronjobs please check out https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler